# JMeter - Wrong number of users in results from remote load testing

Tags: jmeter

I was using non-GUI mode to perform a remote load testing with Jmeter from master server (Linux) to 5 slave servers (Linux). 5x "n" users have been run, "n" users on each server.
The results have been written to master server. 
There are samples from all servers in results file but they relate to the number of active users from particular servers ("n") and not from all servers (5x "n").
There are no information in the result file about the real number of active users on all the servers.
As a result, a maximum number of active users is "n" on generated graphs which does not reflect the real load (5x "n" users).
Has anyone got a similar problem?
Is there anything I can do to correct the results already gathered?
Should I change any JMeter parameter to get the correct results in the next run?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

This is normal and no, there's nothing in JMeter you can do to fix it.

**Long Answer:**

Each Load Generator creates a number of threads `n`: the threads will be numbered 1-n. When the Controller collects all of the information, it sees 5 results for Thread 1, 5 results for Thread 2, ... Thread n. The Controller has no way of knowing that each of them are 5 separate concurrent threads and not just the same thread 5 sequential times.

**Fixing it:**
It depends on what you mean by `a maximum number of active users is "n" on generated graphs`. If this is something inside JMeter, then no, you can't fix it.

If it's a report-generator that you have created yourself, then yes, you can fix it by passing in the number of load generators.